# Why isn't including this 'bigInt' script working? (p5.js web editor)

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I'm following [The Coding Train](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Xy-LMAfglE&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bePNiZLnglXUp2LXIjlCdb&index=15) and learning about the [p5.js](http://p5js.org) library. In this particular exercise, I want to work with potentially massive integers, so I looked around and found [peterolson/BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/).

I attempted to include this script in my project in the same way the p5.js library itself is included, and as suggested in BigInteger's readme:

```
<script src="http://peterolson.github.com/BigInteger.js/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
```

However, after doing so, I still get `bigInt is not defined` errors when I try to reference it from my `script.js`.

Could anyone help me understand what I'm missing? You can see my project in the p5.js web editor [here!](https://editor.p5js.org/Bixbite/sketches/HJBideit7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like these are best answered by looking at your [developer tools](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools). Check out the JavaScript console and the network log to see the error you're getting.

Basically, you can't reference files on GitHub the way you're trying to reference `BigInteger.min.js`. You either need to find a CDNS that hosts the file for you, or you need to upload it to your sketch and reference it via a relative url.

Comment: Oh, I see! I guess I was expecting the error to appear in the web editor console, but I'll check the JS console as well from now on.

Saving a local copy and uploading it into my project did indeed fix the problem, thanks!